# Function returning more than expected

Tags: javascript

I want to without creating a global variable return a single number (1) every time I call the function count, and everytime I do so, increment it by 1. In this example, its supposed to return 1 2 3, which it DOES, but it also returns

```
function() {
  x++
  return x;
}
```

```js
function counter() {
  var x = 0;
  return function() {
    x++
    return x;
  }
}

var count = counter();

console.log('counter() returns: ' + count);
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
console.log('invoking the function returns: ' + count());
```

Comment: Yes, if you try to print a function without calling it, it (usually) shows the code of the function itself. What did you expect the first console.log line to print instead?

Comment: You want `count` to magically return a new number every time you mention it ***without*** you having to *call* it using `()`…?

Comment: You already creating a global variable `var count`

Comment: Thats my bad, I meant the value that is used to increment can't be global

Answer (score -2):

You may want to override the toString method:

```
function counter() {
 var x = 0;
  function internal() {
    x++
   return x;
 }
internal.toString=function(){return internal().toString()};
return internal;
};

console.log(counter());//1
var count=counter();
console.log(count);//1
console.log(count);//2
```

http://jsbin.com/lenigadoqe/edit?console

That works whenever you try to output the function as a string, either trough logging it, or trough count+"". However, thats not always so you may have a look at getters / setters.

Comment: @downvoters: sorry misunderstood question, please see edit

Comment: Problem: it's not guaranteed that the return value will always be used in a *string context*; this works in this specific demo, but what about `arr.push(count)` or other uses?